# How to replace a letter with another letter in a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace, textbox

Say I want to target a specific letter in a textbox region and replace it with another letter using either jquery or javascript, how would I do that and still be able to target another letter afterwards, and again, and again etc.? The letter to change and what it will be changed to will be inputed from either a textbox or a dropdown (whichever is easier)

P.S I tried jQuery's replace function and it didn't work (I probably didn't use it correctly though :)

```
$( "button" ).click( function() {
    $( "Changed" ).replaceWith( $( "New" )        );
});
```

Comment: Could you post your code so we could see what exactly you tried?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/clarinetking/6cLgghme/ Also, I know that change isn't a valid item as it's not a div or something like that (probably a fancy term somewhere)

Comment: UPDATED: Shows what I mean better: http://jsfiddle.net/clarinetking/6cLgghme/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var old = $("#Changed").val();
    var replacement = $("#New").val();
    var regexp = new RegExp(old, 'g');
    $("#Input").val(function(i, current) {
        return current.replace(regexp, replacement);
    });
});
```

1. You need to use `#` before IDs to select them.
2. You need to get the values of the inputs using `.val()`.
3. jQuery's `.replaceWith` is for replacing entire DOM elements, not changing the value of an input.
4. You use `.val()` to change the value of the input. When the argument is a function, the function gets called with the current value as a parameter, and the return value is put in its place.
5. The Javascript method `.replace()` is used to perform replacements in strings. To do multiple replacements, you need to use a `RegExp` with the `g` flag.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/6cLgghme/5/)

Comment: Thanks :) It even changes everything in one go! What's regexp?

Answer (score 1):

Please Check following code if it helps : http://jsfiddle.net/La2y734g/2/

HTML as follows

```
<textarea id="Input" cols="50" rows="5">This textbox has been given a name of "myTextBox". This can be used by any script that process the contents of this textbox (once it's been submitted to the server).</textarea>
<br>Replace
<input type="text" id="replace">with
<input type="text" id="with">
<button>Detect Single Letters And Replace</button>
```

Javascript as follows

```
$("button").on("click", function () {
    //$( "#Input" ).replaceWith( $( "Change" )                 );
    var toReplace = $('#replace').val();
    var withText = $('#with').val();
    var newText = $("#Input").val().replace(toReplace, withText );
    $("#Input").val(newText);
});
```

Comment: YOU ARE AMAZING!! I would love to understand how it works though :) Does the .val mean the stuff inside it? How does it all gel together? THANKS AGAIN :D

Comment: @Clarinetking the val() means the text inside the textbox or its value. Once he gets it he is replacing its value with the value you want and then applying it once again to the value of Input.

Comment: I changed the code to make it easier to understand for you.

Comment: This only replaces the first instance of the replaced character